# How to use VueJs plugin vue-lazyload

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

Im following the step by step docs guide to use the plugin and i still cant see it working

1. VueJs 2x
2. VueCLI 3.9.3

main.js

```
import VueLazyload from 'vue-lazyload'
Vue.use(VueLazyload)
```

component

```
<div v-lazy-container="{ selector: 'img' }">
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1677275/pexels-photo-1677275.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1173777/pexels-photo-1173777.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2827400/pexels-photo-2827400.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">  
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1612461/pexels-photo-1612461.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">  
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/979003/pexels-photo-979003.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">  
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2444444/pexels-photo-2444444.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">  
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/949380/pexels-photo-949380.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">  
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1656579/pexels-photo-1656579.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">  
</div>
```

The objetive is to load images on the viewport but it loads all the photos

Comment: What do you want exactly? Can you explain more?

Comment: hello @eightball im trying to make my images component lazy load, as i said i was trying to use vue-lazy-load plugin, but it wont work, it still loading all the images at the same time

Comment: pexels.com has a very low latency and sends images very fast. You can try with your own proxy and add a pause to see the result

Comment: All your images are displayed in your markup, what do you expect to be lazy loaded ? Add display conditions on your images.

Comment: @eightball let me try another api

Comment: @kursus let me try using the 100vh container and back to you

Comment: also @AlexHunter also try throttle feature in Chrome to check more properly the result https://umaar.com/dev-tips/66-network-throttling-profiles/

Comment: @kursus You were right, the installation was good but i miss the display conditions and all the images loaded at the same time, please type your answer to vote you up!

Answer (score 0):

the error was that I needed to fix a size to the container so that the library could work, this way the images were not loaded all at the same time. (just add height)

```
<div v-lazy-container="{ selector: 'img' }" style='height: 500px;'>
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1677275/pexels-photo-1677275.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1173777/pexels-photo-1173777.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2827400/pexels-photo-2827400.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">  
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1612461/pexels-photo-1612461.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">  
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/979003/pexels-photo-979003.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">  
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2444444/pexels-photo-2444444.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">  
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/949380/pexels-photo-949380.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">  
  <img data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1656579/pexels-photo-1656579.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">  
</div>
```